# Numeric computation of certain symbols in numpy array of sympy expressions

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numerical-methods

## Problem

I am working with an arbitrary MxN numpy matrix where each element is a sympy expression, potentially with differing symbols. For the purposes of visualization, let's work with the following matrix `test`

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

a,b,c=sp.symbols('a b c');
test=np.array([[a**2,a+b],[a*c+b,b/c]]);
```

When run, `test` will look like:

```
In [25]: test
Out[25]: 
array([[a**2, a + b],
       [a*c + b, b/c]], dtype=object)
```

I would like to be able to replace one variable in this array with a number and return a new array that has the same dimensions as `test` but has replaced the specified variable with it's new value. For example, if I wanted to replace `b` with 2, the new array should look like:

```
array([[a**2, a + 2],
       [a*c + 2, 2/c]], dtype=object)
```

## Attempt at a Solution

I first tried to use the sympy function `subs` but I received the following error:

```
test.subs({b:2})
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-a9a04d63af37>", line 1, in <module>
    test.subs({b:2})

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

I looked at using lambdify but I believe that it returns a numeric lambda expression which isn't what I want. I need a new symbolic expression, just one that doesn't depend on `b` anymore. I found some literature in the Wolfram Mathematica documentation under pattern matching that seems to be what I need http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/patterns/ but I can't figure out how to implement this in Python, or if it's even possible to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `sympy.Matrix` to construct symbolic matrices (with sympy expressions as elements) rather than `nympy.array`. If you define `test` as such, the `subs` method works fine.

Comment: Thanks, this should work for me. The purpose of having my expression in a numpy array was to keep the mathematical functionality but I will look into converting it to a sympy Matrix before I need to make a substitution.

Comment: I would not recommend combining sympy and numpy functions. Try to perform symbolic computations using strictly sympy tools. After you are done, translate your sympy results to numpy with `sympy.lambdify` if you need to perform fast numeric computations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `sympy`.  No need for `numpy`, at least not for the substitution:

```
In [117]: import sympy
In [118]: a,b,c=sympy.symbols('a b c')

In [120]: M=sympy.Matrix([[a**2, a+b],[a*c+b, b/c]])
In [121]: M
Out[121]: 
Matrix([
[   a**2, a + b],
[a*c + b,   b/c]])

In [123]: M.subs({b:2})
Out[123]: 
Matrix([
[   a**2, a + 2],
[a*c + 2,   2/c]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Marking this the accepted answer as it is closest to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

array is not an expression, therefore it has not the method subs

Comment: Try to provide the alternative solution as well as telling her the limitations of the situation.